# Check which INI file section has a specific key

Tags: bash

I have an ini file, which can only have two states. State one:

```
[General]
StartWithLastProfile=0

[Profile0]
Name=default
IsRelative=1
Path=Profiles/kn081mln.default
Default=1

[Profile1]
Name=Dark
IsRelative=1
Path=Profiles/elqlrk57.Dark
```

State two:

```
[General]
StartWithLastProfile=0

[Profile0]
Name=default
IsRelative=1
Path=Profiles/kn081mln.default

[Profile1]
Name=Dark
IsRelative=1
Path=Profiles/elqlrk57.Dark
Default=1
```

The difference between the two is whether section `Profile0` or `Profile1` has the key `Default=1`. How can I check under which of these two sections `Default=1` is using bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
awk '/\[Profile[01]\]/ {label=$0} /Default/ {print label}'
```

Explanation:

If a line matches the categorical label, remember the current category.

The category pattern I use here is `\[Profile[01]\]`. Since `[]` is treated as a set when not escaped, the literal `[]` must be escaped, and the `[01]` is used as the character set.

If the desired key appears, output the label.

Comment: Yep, works. Marked as a solution as it is simpler than my solution using Python.

Answer (score 1):

After some tinkering, figured out this could be done with some Python inside bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
foo=$(python - << EOF
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('/path/to/file.ini')

if config.has_option('Profile0', 'Default'):
    print('Default is Profile0')
else:
    print('Default is Profile1')
EOF)

echo $foo
```